# Is there a way to make objdump read from STDIN instead of a file?

Tags: linux, bash, stdin

In my specific case, I want to use it to dump what I `echo`.
I don't want to involve any file...
Is there a way to make `objdump` read from `STDIN` instead?

Comment: Could you please explain your situation a little more?

Answer (score 9):

You can't. There is no way around that, you will have to use the temporary file.

Source file readelf.c has this unconditional check (in binutils 2.22-8 at least) before even attempting to open the file:

```
if (! S_ISREG (statbuf.st_mode))
    {
      error (_("'%s' is not an ordinary file\n"), file_name);
      return 1;
    }
```

So if the file is anything but regular file (like symlink, or char device as in case of `/dev/stdin`, `/proc/self/fd/*`, etc.) it won't work.

Alternatively, you could modify the source and use modified objdump, but there goes your portability.

Answer (score 4):

you can always do

```
objdump -d /dev/stdin < t2.o
```

or

```
cat t2.o | objdump -d /dev/stdin
```

sample

> [root@myhost cc]# objdump  -h /dev/stdin < t2.o
>
> /dev/stdin:     file format elf64-x86-64
>
> Sections: Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA
>   File off  Algn   0 .group        00000008  0000000000000000 
>   0000000000000000  00000040  2**2
>                     CONTENTS, READONLY, EXCLUDE, GROUP, LINK_ONCE_DISCARD

Comment: `cat t2.o | objdump -d /dev/stdin` does not work. `/dev/stdin` only works when it corresponds to a real file. Since your solution requires the presence of that file, this does not answer the OP.

Comment: This may work for this invocation of `objdump` in particular, but it might fail for others in case it does `seek` operations on the file. When tools don't have `-` for stdin, that is often the case.

Answer (score 1):

`llvm-objdump` accepts stdin input with standard `-` option. `llvm-objdump` cli options mimic gnu `objdump` for all common usecases.

Example usage:
`clang src.c -c -o - | llvm-objdump -d -`

Answer (score 0):

I used `ndisasm -b 64 -` as a workaround.

e.g.
I wanted:

`echo 41 89 1b | xxd -r -p | objdump -d -`

But the above doesn't work.
This does work though:

`echo 41 89 1b | xxd -r -p | ndisasm -b 64 -`

Comment: I bit more of explanation would be great to understand what are you doing

Comment: afaik ndisasm is only for x86. it can't work with arm, for example.

Answer (score -1):

A kind of workaround is using `tee`. So to disassemble a file named `input` use

```
cat input | tee a.out | objdump -d
```

---

And, to give an example for passing some bytes with the `echo` command, the following should be a good example (The parameters are [described in this good SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34424146/1305969)):

To disassemble the x86 code byte sequence

```
b8 01 00 00 00 bb 0a 00 00 00 cd 80
```

prefix it with `0:` and use the command

```
echo "0: b8 01 00 00 00 bb 0a 00 00 00 cd 80" | xxd -r | tee a.out | objdump -D -Mintel,i386 -b binary -m i386
```

Its output is:

```
a.out:     file format binary
Disassembly of section .data:
00000000 <.data>:
   0:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x1
   5:   bb 0a 00 00 00          mov    ebx,0xa
   a:   cd 80                   int    0x80
```

which is just the assembly code for exiting an i386 linux program with the exit code 0xA.